# How to Redefine the fbox Command to Increase the Default Space Between It and the Beginning of the Subsequent Sentence

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, fbox, horizontal

Here is a MWE that displays the use of the `\fbox` command in multiple paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\parskip 10pt
\Large
{\color{red}{\textbf{\fbox{1.}}}} I would like to (permanently) add a little bit of horizontal space between the boxed number and the first word of the sentence following it---so that whenever I invoke the fbox command in the document, it adds such a horizontal space automatically.

{\color{red}{\textbf{\fbox{2.}}}} \lipsum[13]

{\color{red}{\textbf{\fbox{3.}}}} \lipsum[14]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How may the `\fbox` command be redefined in order to increase the default space between the box it produces and the first word of the the following sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to define your own command:

```
\newcommand{\start}[1]{%
  \par
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\bfseries #1.}}%
  \hspace{0.8em}% or what you prefer
  \ignorespaces
}
```

Full example; the third call shows that's immaterial whether you have a space after `\start{3}` or not.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\start}[1]{%
  \par
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\bfseries #1.}}%
  \hspace{0.8em}% or what you prefer
  \ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}

\start{1} I would like to (permanently) add a little bit of 
horizontal space between the boxed number and the first word 
of the sentence following it---so that whenever I invoke the 
fbox command in the document, it adds such a horizontal space 
automatically.

\start{2} \lipsum[13]

\start{3}\lipsum[14]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you know of a way to keep the name `\fbox` for the command? I have a document that often has used `\fbox` and if possible, I would like not to have to change all of them to something else.